# Deriving combined gas law from Boyle's and Charles' laws

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas

I know that the combined gas law, $$\frac{PV}{T}=k$$ should be derivable from Boyle's Law and Charles' Law. Since these are very basic equations, I presumed that it would be a simple matter, so I tried it myself.

Charles' Law is $$\frac{V}{T}=k_1$$ and Boyle's Law is $$PV=k_2$$The subscripts are arbitrary. In the derivation on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combined_gas_law), they jump from this to $$PV=k_2T$$

I'm sure I'm just overlooking something silly, but I see no way of combining Charles' and Boyle's to achieve an equation in which we don't cancel at least one of $P$, $V$, or $T$.

What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: According to Boyle's law:
At constant temperature a volume gas is inversely proportionally to applied pressure this is boyle's law.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have to realize first that Charles' law is the change in volume with respect to temperature *for constant pressure* while Boyle's law is the change in volume with respect to pressure *for constant temperature*. So when you combine them, you need to account for these

If I take a gas of volume $V_1$, pressure $P_1$ and temperature $T_1$ and let it change have a state $(V_*,\,P_2,\,T_1)$, then via Boyle's law,
$$
P_1V_1=P_2V_*\tag{1}
$$
Then keeping this constant pressure we move to state $(V_2,\,P_2,\,T_2)$ via Charles' law,
$$
\frac{V_*}{T_1}=\frac{V_2}{T_2}\tag{2}
$$
Solving for $V_*$ in both (1) and (2) then equating them, we get
$$
\frac{P_1V_1}{T_1}=\frac{P_2V_2}{T_2}
$$
We've changed the pressure, volume and temperature of the gas but still find their product equal, suggesting that the relation is constant:
$$
\frac{PV}{T}=k
$$

Comment: Thanks Kyle - exactly what I was looking for. Seems the tricky thing in Thermo is always knowing which values to keep constant. I'd upvote your answer, but I just joined and don't have the reputation yet :P

Comment: Can $k$ be expressed in terms of the constants of proportionality of Boyle's and Charle's experimental laws?

Answer (score 3):

Once you have the two laws for isothermic and isochoric processes for a perfect gas, you can deduce the state equation.

We assume that there exists a “set of possible configurations $(P,V,T)$”, where the two laws (isothermal, isochoric) are both satisfied: $$PV=\phi (T),\quad T=P\xi (V),$$
for some functions $\phi,\xi$.
We can then show that $\phi$ is the multiplication by a constant and $ \xi = \phi ^{-1}$ .

**Proof.** If $P=1$, $$V=\phi(T)=\phi(\xi (V)).$$ Since $\xi$ is surjective, $\phi = \xi ^{-1}$. With $V=1$ we have  $$\xi(P)=\xi (\phi(T))=T=P\xi(1).$$ So $\xi$ is the multiplication by $\xi (1)$, q.e.d.

Answer (score 1):

> Charles' Law is $$\frac{V}{T}=k_1$$ and Boyle's Law is $$PV=k_2$$The
> subscripts are arbitrary.

Instead: \begin{align}\frac VT=f(P)\\
PV=g(T),\tag1\end{align} where the functions $f$ and $g$ are not identically zero. (When two proportional variables are varying against each other, every other relevant variable in the system is being fixed at a constant value.)

Thus, $$P\times f(P)=\frac{g(T)}T.$$ Since $P$ and $T$ are independent variables, $\big(P\times f(P)\big)$ and $\dfrac{g(T)}T$ must be a (nonzero) constant, say $k.$ Then, substituting $g(T)=kT$ into $(1)$ gives the combined gas law $$\frac{PV}{T}=k,$$ as required.

Answer (score -2):

The volume of a fixed mass of gas is inversely proportional to its pressure at constant temperature. This is known as Boyle's law.

$$P_{1}V_{1}=P{2}V_{2}$$
$$PV= {\rm a\, constant}$$
$$P\, {\rm inversely\, proportional\, to}\, \frac{1}{V}\, {\rm at\, constant}\, T$$
$$PV = {\rm a\, constant} T$$

This is the mathematical equation or algebraic law for Boyle's law.